# Cannot execute lsusb

Tags: command-line, usb, keyboard

I'm trying to discover the USB VID for a keyboard that I intend to use as a second keyboard for macros.  I have found a tutorial that tells me to use the command `lsusb` to discover this, but when I try to type `lsusb` in the terminal it does not work, stating that the command was not found.

How can I use this command? I use Xubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What release or flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Xubuntu Xenial.  I have added the appropriate flags.

Comment: Have you tried running it with sudo?

Comment: Yes, I have, and it gives the same error of `command not found`.

Comment: A `whereis lsusb` on my later system shows it's in /usr/bin/, a `dpkg -S` tells me mine is in `usbutils` package from 'main'. Is that installed? fyi: Xubuntu being a flavor reached EOL last month for the desktop so consider upgrade (only packages from 'main' or those found in main Ubuntu 16.04 are now supported & receive updates; https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-16-04-1-release)

Comment: Thank you!  I installed usbutils, and now I can run the command!

Comment: @dessert flavors are not supported for 5 years, that's 'main' repo only, here it was Xubuntu desktop that had reached EOL (*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will be supported for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Core, and Ubuntu Kylin. All other flavours will be supported for 3 years.* https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system `lsusb` runs, so I look for the file

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   whereis lsusb
lsusb: /usr/bin/lsusb /usr/share/man/man8/lsusb.8.gz
```

I look for what package the command is found

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   dpkg -S /usr/bin/lsusb
usbutils: /usr/bin/lsusb
```

At this point I'd probably have the answer you want, ie. ensure that package is installed, on my box I can use

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   apt-cache policy usbutils
usbutils:
  Installed: 1:010-3
  Candidate: 1:010-3
  Version table:
 *** 1:010-3 500
        500 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

or in summary; check you have `usbutils` installed, and `sudo apt install usbutils` if you don't.

Comment: this worked because I have it installed;  the `whereis` of course would fail on a box which didn't have it installed, so I'd have to `apt search` or different commands if it wasn't installed on this box.